# click event listener interfere with onclick()

Tags: javascript, user-interface, frontend

I build a popup search box, that open if I click on search btn or press any key on keyboard.
for closing popup, press esc key AND press close button AND click outside the search box will do the job.
but I faced a problem, for open popup using search button, I use onclick attribute and call a function
and for closing popup if I click outside the popup, I used click event listener, and these interfere with each other, so when I click on search button, popup will open and immediately click event listener closes the popup !!!!
so what should I do ?!

search btn:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="openSearch()"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
```

opensearch() function:

```
  function openSearch() {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("search-field").focus();
  }
```

event listener for outside click:

```
    document.addEventListener ('click', function(event) {
  // Detect outside clicks
  var isClickInside = document.getElementById('PopupSearchWrapper').contains(event.target);
  if (!isClickInside) {
    closeSearch();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(using [bulma css classes](https://bulma.io/))

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
<div class="modal" id="search">
     <div class="modal-background" id='back'></div>
     <div class="modal-card">
          <button class="delete" id="result-close"></button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Because the background and the card are siblings (with high z-index) then what's not the card will be the background. Simply set the background and close button `.onclick` to `closeSearch()`

key CSS properties

```
html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.modal{
    align-items:center;
    display:none; // display: flex when active
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:40
}
.modal-background {
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0
}
```